# If you assign a property to an Object, can you make it changes as the object changes?

Tags: javascript, object

I was testing with the basic with the below code

```
var A={};
var B={name:"come"};
A.pro=B;
B=null;
//Here A.pro is still point to normal B, not to a null
```

How should I do this if I want when B changes, A.pro will also change?

Comment: That's cause `A.pro` has nothing to do with `B` once it's declared. If you want to change `A.pro` you have to explicitly say so. `A.pro = null` for example.

Comment: might be worth giving a use case or what you are trying to achieve. because there is no reason you'd have that code in a working application its hard to answer in a useful way

Comment: Try with `A.bro=()=>B`

Comment: @atmd, sometimes, you need a reference to an object but, if directly assigned, it would fail, because you need a second reference to it. if you assign the object directly, you could loose the reference to it. practical example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44005308/1447675), where all arrays are wrapped by an object `groups[b] = { values: [] };`.

Comment: `var A = {get pro() { return B; }}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function, like :

```js
var A = {};
var B = {
  name: "come"
};

A.pro = function() {
  return B
};

// or with arrow function
// A.pro = () => B;

B = null;
console.log(A.pro());
```

---

### Other way

If you want to update `B` value with `A.pro()`, you can use an optional parameter, like :

```js
var A = {};
var B = {
  name: "come"
};

A.pro = function(newVal) {
  (typeof newVal === 'undefined') ? false : (B = newVal);
  return B;
};

B = null;
console.log(A.pro());
A.pro(4);
console.log(A.pro());
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a nested approach with an additional object.

```js
var a = {},
  b = { data: { name: "come" } };

a.pro = b;
console.log(a);

b.data = null;
console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This one seems really interesting. Do you know why simply add another layer for b would make this work? I mean if there is any principle of Javascript that this belongs to?

Comment: it is more because of the structure of objects in javascript. if you assign a (primitive) value to an object, the reference to the object `A` stays but `B` in your example has lost the reference. the rule is assigning a new value to an object deletes the reference to a former assigned object.